# How can I create a loop to click all buttons of a page using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have 60 buttons on a page and I want to click all of them. Is it possible to create a loop to do so?

XPATH for the buttons:

/html/body/form/div[3]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/div/ct-polling-activity/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[**1**]/td[6]/div/i

/html/body/form/div[3]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/div/ct-polling-activity/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[**2**]/td[6]/div/i

The only different number for them is the last tr[ ], being a sequence until it reaches 60.

This is the function that I'm using to click the buttons.

```
def explicit_wait_xpath(my_selector):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
                                                my_selector)))
    element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the question you asked, I think you can just create a loop, dynamically update the selector and pass it to function call.

```
def explicit_wait_xpath(my_selector):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,my_selector)))                                                  
    element.click()


for i in range(1,61):
   # use of f-string
   selector = f'"/html/body/form/div[3]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/div/ct-polling-activity/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[6]/div/i"'
   explicit_wait_xpath(selector)
```